Error: Unable to initialize tables - sqlBoiler
I am trying to build models using sqlboiler sql command. But the below error is occurring.
unable to load tables: unable to fetch table column info(user_info) : unable to scan for table user_info: sql: Scan error on column index 1, name "column_type" : converting NULL to string is unsupported
Error: unable to initialize tables: unable to fetch table data: exit status 1

Could someone please help me to resolve this?
I thought there were problems in connection between sqlboiler and psql. But it was connected properly.

First, can you try this one:
go get -u github.com/volatiletech/sqlboiler/v4
go get -u github.com/lib/pq

Is your target table empty? Can you give me the result of a SELECT command?
Maybe your table and model variables do not have the same data types.
